# Apache conf to nginx conf to avoid CORS

Tags: angularjs, apache, nginx

In our local development setup we have a pure client application build on Angular JS that connects to services hosted on different servers.

In order to avoid CORS in our dev environment we configured Apache as proxy as given below

```
#Apache Configuration
<VirtualHost *:*>
DocumentRoot "../apps"
ProxyPreserveHost On

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

ProxyPass /env2/ https://env2-abc.com/
ProxyPassReverse /env2/ https://env2-abc.com/

ServerName localhost:9000
</VirtualHost>
```

I wanted to setup nginx for the same configuration but I am facing CORS issue

```
#nginx configuration
server {
    rewrite_log on;
    listen 9090;
    server_name localhost;
    root ../apps;
    index index.html;

    location /env2 {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    
        proxy_pass https:///env2-abc.com;           
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me setup the proxy and reverse proxy correctly. The apache conf is running perfectly as of now but I want to try nginx for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the above problem using the following configuration in the nginx xonf file

```
server {
    rewrite_log on;
    listen 9000;
    server_name localhost;
    root ../apps;
    index index.html;
    access_log off; # I do not need logging in dev env
    error_log off;  # I do not need logging in dev env

    location /env2/ { # trailing / gets substituted by proxy_pass
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_pass              https://env2-abc.com/;
    }
}
```